# Brew Doctor Warning moncefbelyamani.com how to Install Xcode, Homebrew, Git, RVM, Ruby & Rails

Tags: installation, warnings, homebrew

When I try to run brew doctor in Terminal it gives me a couple of warnings. How do I get rid of them the easiest way. Could I just delete the files...?! Also I installed the current Command Line Tools but it sais it´s not updated?

I´m trying to follow through parts of this tutorial right now http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/

this is returned when running brew doctor:

```
Warning: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework detected
This can be picked up by CMake's build system and likely cause the build to
fail. You may need to move this file out of the way to compile CMake.

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i32.2.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i64.2.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.6.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i32.la
    /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i64.la

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/osxfuse.pc

Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available
Update them from Software Update in the App Store.
```

also when I run gcc -v it gives me this, so my command line tools are up to date, are they?

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: I fixed these issues with four steps: 1)Uninstall Mono Framework (see: discussions.apple.com/message/23529126#23529126) 2)Uninstall OSXFuse(got to system preferences, update it first, it didn´t uninstall before I did that) 3)Make sure you get the latest version of XCode, my version didn´t update for some reason so I had to install a new one. 4)type: sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.6.dylib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed these issues with four steps:

1. Uninstall Mono Framework (see:
   discussions.apple.com/message/23529126#23529126)
2. Uninstall
       OSXFuse(got to system preferences, update it first, it    didn´t
       uninstall before I did that)
3. Make sure you get the latest version
       of XCode, my version didn´t    update for some reason so I had to
       install a new one.
4. type: sudo rm
           /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.6.dylib